# How present a Authendication view controller Like Google and Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to present a view controller for authenticate from web. For this I like to present view controller like exactly how Google and facebook did on their login services.

How to present this authentication web view controller? Please refer attached screenshots. Thanks in advance...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved very easily by using **Google's Firebase**.  Try have a look at [FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't get your answer. I've to develop my own SDK exactly like Web Auth how google & facebook doing.

Comment: @Noob You can consider using `Cocoapods` to download `FirebaseUI` and use it directly in your project.

Comment: @MiguelTepale, Sorry I can't understand why are you suggest FirebaseUI. I am developing my own SDK for auth. So,  I am not going to use Google or Facebook for login. Instead I am going to use my own one. But, I don't know the OAuth flow How Google & Facebook presenting their Auth view controller + WebView. That's what I want to know.

Comment: @Noob Apologies, it makes sense now. I believe you can only get that functionality if you  install Google's or Facebook's software to get the the Auth view controller. I'm not sure if you can programmatically create it yourself. Check out the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) or maybe a follow up question to ask on SO.